# When a last name contains "Saint", is it ever spelled out, or is it always "St."?

Tags: abbreviations, names

When a last name contains "Saint", such as Richard St. Paul, how does "Saint" show up on this person's legal documents etc.?

Is their legal name "Richard Saint Paul", "Richard Saint-Paul", or "Richard St. Paul"?

Why is it this way as opposed to another?

Comment: [Playback](https://playback.fm/people/first-name/saint) lists some famous(?) people with Saint/St as their given name. Both the full version and the abbreviated form are used; it's the choice of the namer and later the named. The same probably applies to surnames, and to legal renditions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how people write their names isn't really a matter of "English usage".

Answer (score 1):

In English Law, in England, you can call yourself whatever you want, providing (I don't know the exact wording) it is not for the purpose of deception in connection with an illegal act).

So when it comes to official documents you can write your name as YOU want, again providing there is no criminal intent.
Leaving aside officially changing your name by deed poll ,which means all documents that had your previous name are legally binding and acceptable with the new name even though they are not physically changed or re-issued.

Perhaps a more complete answer can be found by a little study here, see what people actually wrote on the documents
https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/